# I wonder what is the limit of the following:

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} {\log_2 k - \lfloor {\log_2 k} \rfloor }$$

Is the limit any well-known number?
If $n=11$, $0.55429$, and
If $n=12$, $0.555676$.
In fact, the limit is the average of sum of fractional part of the function $f(x)=\log_2 x$. Would you give any comments on this?

Comment: In fact, I obtained an upper bound $2 - 1/log(2)$ using the inverse function($g(x)=2^x$).

Comment: $2- \frac{1}{log(2)} = 0.5573049591110366......$

Comment: $$ \lfloor\log_2(k)\rfloor=p\iff p\leqslant\log_2(k)<p+1\iff 2^p\leqslant k<2^{p+1} $$
Therefore
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{2^n}\left(\log_2(k)-\lfloor\log_2(k)\rfloor\right)=\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{k=2^p}^{2^{p+1}-1}\log_2(k)-p2^p\right) $$
However
$$\sum_{k=2^p}^{2^{p+1}-1}\log_2(k)=\log_2\left((2^{p+1}-1)!\right)-\log_2\left((2^p-1)!\right)$$ Using Stirling's formula may help to evalutate this sum